# Actual number of iterations

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I am currently using TF 2.1. When using `model.fit` with `tf.data.Dataset`, it shows me that the number of iterations is **2044/2043**. So my question is, how many batches of data are actually produced? 2044 or 2043?

[image: s]

Answer (score 0):

Number of batches = total number of samples in dataset/batch size.
If the total samples are not completely divisible by batch size, then it will take the remaining in the next batch.

Eg: `15x66+10=1000` which means it will take 66 batches of size 15 and for the final steps it takes only 10.